# Can I install Xposed framework and run GravityBox on stock and rooted Android 4.2.2?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, xposed-framework

I'm using a Karbonn A52+ running rooted Android 4.2.2 (stock), and haven't installed any custom recovery or ROMs. Can I run the GravityBox with Xposed framework on my device? I've heard rumors that Xposed framework works on devices running Android  version above 4.4. So I don't want to take the risk of installing it on my device.

Comment: You need *at least* root access in order to install the Xposed Framework. I doubt your stock ROM is rooted. Only devices running Android > 5 need to install the framework through a custom recovery.

Comment: my phone has root access

Answer (score 1):

Xposed framework is designed to work on all Jelly Bean devices and up. All you need to do is rooting the phone first. Similarly Gravity Box. There are 3 different variants like JB, KK, L which we know in Xposed modules store. In your case use Gravity Box (JB)  with latest xposed framework. A quick tutorial for future readers - Install Xposed installer > Install Xposed framework from within the app > Search for Gravity Box module and install it > Activate and reboot. That's it. Gravity Box is also available in Play Store.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. Shall I download from here? http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer

Comment: @TanmayVij Correct. Download, install, launch it. Then download and install [Gravitybox](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox). A notification would come up to activate the module and reboot the device. Do it. All good now!